# React.js Expected onSubmit listener to be a function, instead got type boolean

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Can someone please tell me what the hell I am doing wrong here? I am pretty new to React, and everything I have read says that this should work. I am trying to call the function "addItem" when the form is submitted, however the console.log throws the error "Expected onSubmit listener to be a function, instead got type boolean" on page load. Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import App from "./App"
import List from "./List"


class AddTodo extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }
  addItem(e){
    var itemArray = this.state.items;
    itemArray.push({
      text: this._inputElement.value,
      key: Date.now()
    })
    this.setState({
      items: itemArray
    })
    this._inputElement.value = "";
    console.log(itemArray)
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  render(){
      return(
        <div className="box-wrapper">
          <form onSubmit={this.addItem.bind(this)}>
            <input href={(a) => this._inputElement = a} placeholder={this.props.placeHolder} type="text"></input>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <List entries={this.state.items} />
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default AddTodo;
```

Comment: On your button, you only pass the prop `onSubmit` which is a boolean (true). You need to pass a handler which is a function.

Comment: You don't need two onSubmits. It's either you set it up on your form, or you do one for your button.

Comment: I have since corrected the typo. Still not working, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your `render` and `addItem` to something like this:

```
  addItem(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    {/* add the rest of the function here */}
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="box-wrapper">
        <form onSubmit={this.addItem.bind(this)}>
          <input
            href={(a) => this._inputElement = a}
            placeholder={this.props.placeHolder}
            type="text"
          />
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.addItem.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <List entries={this.state.items} />
      </div>
  )
```

}

I made two important changes:

1. Added `e.preventDefault();` to the `addItem` method, which will prevent default behavior.
2. Added an `onClick` handler to the "submit" button, with the `addItem` method passed in as the target executable.

Comment: You're welcome!  If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as correct :-)

Comment: I can confirm while following along with the book called [Learning React](https://www.amazon.com/Learning-React-Kirupa-Chinnathambi/dp/0134546318) by Kirupa Chinnatathambi this was fixes the issue found in Chapter 15

Answer (score 1):

First have to remove event.preventDefault .It is restricting the default behaviour of the webpage.Add a onClick event listener to the submit so that the function executes on button click.

```
`import React, { Component } from 'react';
import App from "./App"
import List from "./List"


class AddTodo extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }
  addItem(e){
    var itemArray = this.state.items;
    itemArray.push({
      text: this._inputElement.value,
      key: Date.now()
    })
    this.setState({
      items: itemArray
    })
    this._inputElement.value = "";
    console.log(itemArray)
   //  e.preventDefault(); remove this prevent default
  }
  render(){
      return(
        <div className="box-wrapper">
          <form onSubmit={this.addItem.bind(this)}>
            <input href={(a) => this._inputElement = a} placeholder={this.props.placeHolder} type="text"></input>
            <button type="submit" onClick={this.addItem.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
          </form>
          <List entries={this.state.items} />
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default AddTodo;`
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting any error. But you should put the `preventDefault` at the top of the `addItem`, this will prevent from page reload. There is better way to handle the input value by assigning `ref` attribute to input and accessing via `this.refs.refName`.

```
addItem(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //To prevent the page reload on submit

  var itemArray = this.state.items;

  itemArray.push({
    text: this.refs.inputElement.value
  });

  this.refs.inputElement.value = ""; // clearing the value
}

render() {
  return( 
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.addItem.bind(this)} >
        <input ref="inputElement" placeholder={this.props.placeHolder} type="text"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
      </form>
      {
        this.state.itemArray.map((item) => {
          return(<span>{item}</span>)
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! While the previous comment answered my initial question, this helped me understand how to insert the map function inside of my render function!

Comment: @IanSpringer Cool!!